# Apollo Federation Gateway can't load when parent service goes down

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-federation

I have 3 services: Org, Gatekeeper and Fleet. Gatekeeper and Fleet extend the Org schema from the Org service. then the Org server is up and running along with fleet and gatekeeper, everything works fine, but if org is down and I try run gateway with just fleet and gatekeeper, I get an error "Unknown Type: Org"

I read in the API reference for apollo that gatekeeper / fleet should run standalone, but does that mean only if I spin up a gatekeeper server? The standalone server DOES work, but not through the gateway if a parent service is down. Is there a way to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apollo docs mean that you should be able to run each of those services independently. For example, imagine that you had only developed gatekeeper and not fleet/org. You can test this by running the server standalone and querying/mutating it. Everything that federation adds to the schema "can be ignored".

However, once you try to run that in a federated environment it cannot be ignored. That is because the directives and other spec changes have meaning to the gateway. They will all have to be up for gateway to work.